# What is wrong with this code for summing variables variances?

Tags: r, matrix, variance

I have a matrix with 11 columns, and I want to sum the columns' variances. I tried using this code:

```
sumVariances = 0
i = 0

while (i < ncol(matrix)){
  sumVariances = sumVariances+ var(matrix[,i])
  i = i + 1
}
```

but at the end of the loop `sumVariances` is an empty 0x0 matrix instead of a number. What is wrong here?

Comment: Process starts with `matrix[,0]` and breaks. Start at `i=1`.

Comment: And don't use the name `matrix` for a data-object.

Comment: Start at `i=1` and switch to an inequality, `<= ncol(m)`

Comment: Or at `i=1` with `< (ncol(m) + 1)` or `!= (ncol(m) + 1)`

Comment: But the simpler approach is something like `sum(apply(m, 2, var))`

Comment: @jbaums - and if you have a really large matrix, `sum(colSums(sweep(mat, 2, colMeans(mat))^2)/(nrow(mat)-1))` will be quick.

Comment: Thanks! Some of you guys please post it as an answer.

Comment: @thelatemail: Wouldn't it be `-2`? (I had already written almost the same comment, save I include the function name, but then deleted it.)

Comment: @BondedDust - I don't think so. `mat <- matrix(1:10); var(mat); colSums(sweep(mat, 2, colMeans(mat))^2)/(nrow(mat)-1);`

Comment: My point was that for sample variance, degrees of freedom is `n-2`.